VSCode Terminal Ignoring First Character Of Input
So, I've been noticing this for a while now, but a lot of times (not every time) when I am using the terminal in VSCode and start typing, the initial first key press doesn't get recognized. I just thought it was a quirk and is easy enough to ignore...
BUT...
I have an extension I have authored that utilizes the terminal to execute commands. I have just noticed that (intermittently) when I call the sendText method, the first character of the string passed into that method also gets ignored.
Given the following code:
const terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal("MyTerminal");

terminal.sendText("cd ..");

I would expect the command being sent to the terminal to be cd .., but in the terminal (and only sometimes) it attempts to execute d .. - which is obviously not what is expected.
Anyone have any ideas?
Issue on the vscode repo

Sometimes this happens to me in Windows Terminal. I have it set to default to Git Bash, and I've never witnessed this by opening Git Bash directly. But sometimes when running Git Bash inside of Windows Terminal it happens.
